# How to combine 2 nested array of object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, array-map

How do I combine 2 nested arrays.
There are 2 Array A and B

```
const A = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "bp": true,
    "ba": "value1",
    "risk": [
      {
        "id": 0.1,
        "rk": false,
        "title": "risk1",
        "control": [
          {
            "id": 0.12,
            "ctl": "ctl1"
          },
          {
            "id": 0.13,
            "ctl": "ctl2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 0.1223,
        "rk": false,
        "title": "risk23"
      }
    ],
    "master": [
      {
        "id": 0.2,
        "mk": false,
        "title": "obli1",
        "control": [
          {
            "id": 0.12,
            "ctl": "ctl1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "bp": true,
    "ba": "value2"
  }
]
```

.

```
const B = [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "bp": true,
        "ba": "value1",
        "risk": [
          {
            "id": 0.1,
            "rk": false,
            "title": "risk1",
            "control": [
              {
                "id": 0.12,
                "ctl": "ctl1"
              },
              {
                "id": 0.13,
                "ctl": "ctl2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "master": [
          {
            "id": 0.2,
            "mk": false,
            "title": "obli1",
            "control": [
              {
                "id": 0.12,
                "ctl": "ctl1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 0.211,
            "mk": true,
            "title": "obli44",
            "control": [
              {
                "id": 0.12,
                "ctl": "ctl1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "bp": true,
        "ba": "value3"
      }
    ]
```

.

on combining **A** and **B** the output should be of below format.
We need to take **risk** from table **A** and we need to take **master** from table **B** and add it to table **C**.

The Final array looks like the following.

.

```
const c = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "bp": true,
    "ba": "value1",
    "risk": [
      {
        "id": 0.1,
        "rk": false,
        "title": "risk1",
        "control": [
          {
            "id": 0.12,
            "ctl": "ctl1"
          },
          {
            "id": 0.13,
            "ctl": "ctl2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 0.1223,
        "rk": false,
        "title": "risk23"
      }
    ],
    "master": [
      {
        "id": 0.2,
        "mk": false,
        "title": "obli1",
        "control": [
          {
            "id": 0.12,
            "ctl": "ctl1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 0.211,
        "mk": true,
        "title": "obli44",
        "control": [
          {
            "id": 0.12,
            "ctl": "ctl1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "bp": true,
    "ba": "value2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "bp": true,
    "ba": "value3"
  }
]
```

The data can be more than 1000 records. please help me with which it will save time and complexity.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please add your code. what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to isolate the IDs from array A and B. You can also map over the two of them concatenated together, but then you may have duplicate values. This seems like a rational way to go about ensuring single entries for each ID.

```js
const allIds = [...a.map(x => x.id), ...b.map(x => x.id)];
const uniqueIds = allIds.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return prev.includes(curr) ? prev : [...prev, curr]
}, []);
```

Then you need to take those `uniqueIds`, and map over each of them. For each ID, you need to return the matching object in A and the matching object in B, but overwrite the `risk` property with the value from the object in A and overwrite the `master` property with the value from the object in B.

That can be done by just finding the matching objects in A and B, and then use the spread operator to assign their entries to the new object.

**Note:** If the properties outside of `risk` and `master` (e.g. `bp` or `ba`) have different values, then the element listed last will overwrite it. In the below case, that means if the `bp` value in A is `true` and the `bp` value in B is `false`, then the `bp` value in C will be `false`.

```js
const c = uniqueIds.map(id => {
  const elementInA = a.find(x => x.id === id);
  const elementInB = b.find(x => x.id === id);
  return {
    ...elementInA,
    ...elementInB,
    risk: [
      ...elementInA?.risk ?? []
    ],
    master: [
      ...elementInB?.master ?? []
    ]
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through multiple times both arrays, I would suggest something that will loop through each array, not more than needed.

The following approach will loop through twice the first array, and once the B array. (not considering the indexOf method).

```
const ids = A.map(({id}) => id), C = A.map(a => a);

for(let b of B){
    let index = ids.indexOf(b.id);
    if(index < 0){
        C.push(b);
    } else {
        C[index] = {
            ...A[index],
            ...b,
            risk: [
                ...A[index]?.risk ?? []
              ],
              master: [
                ...b?.master ?? []
              ] 
        }
    }
}
```